# Define a range of cells. Like Shift + Click

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With this formula `=AVERAGE(A1:F5)`
I want to do something like this `=AVERAGE(A1:A1+5)`

Where I can define a range of cells.
I tried OFFSET formula but it does ctrl+click where I need Shift+click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OFFSET is Volatile I prefer INDEX:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,5))
```

You can then replace the `1` and `5` with a cell reference in which you put the desired row numbers.

Comment: Can I go backwards too? like =AVERAGE(INDEX(A:F,,5):INDEX(A:F,,-1))?

Comment: @ggmkp No, that is the relative column number so you would need to use 4 and 5.  You will need to do the math instead.